# POST form with changing amount of inputs in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, post

I'd like to handle a POST form with a changing amount of inputs in Symfony2. This form is used to create a quiz, so the user can add as many questions and answers to each question as he wants.

It can basically give something like this, `Quiz`, `Question` and `Answer` each being Doctrine entities:

```
- Quiz
  - Question 1
    - Answer 1.1
    - Answer 1.2
  - Question 2
    - Answer 2.1
    - Answer 2.2
    - Answer 2.3
```

For other stuff I've used the 'regular' method to handle forms (creating a `Form` object in the controller based on the entity and the type, and making it handle the `Request`), but this obviously won't work here as the number of inputs can vary.

Is there a proper way to handle such requests in Symfony2 or do I have to iterate through each POST variable and validate them one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually pretty good explained in the symfony2 documentation.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

You do the mapping between entities, bind the form and use some javascript (or other method) to make the frontend work.

(http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html might come in handy)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to [dynamically modify your form using form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html),

You can then build your form while binding it to your request so that it fits the structure of what was send by the user. (I already did it and it's working fine).

It's all about adding [Event Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class) to your form class. Your event subscriber should then build your form on the appropriate [Form Event](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/FormEvents.html) (BIND_CLIENT_DATA in your case, if you need to do it on bind).

Take a deeper look on [this part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-user-data) of [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).